# To what extent is mass required for electricity and memory retention?

Tags: internal-consistency

I'm sorry if this this question doesn't meet the complexity standards, but my understanding of electricity is rather basic. Here goes!

Memories are stored through rapidly firing neurons, but to what extent is mass required in this process?

To put this into more concrete terms:

Assuming an entirely massless being, are there (scientifically plausible) ways this being could even retain memories?

Comment: If you're imagining a massless being, you're already deeply outside of what is scientifically plausible. How do you expect us to assess how plausible you're critter's ability to store memories is without knowing how you plan on handwaving the whole not-composed-of-mass part?

Comment: Electricity consists of moving objects that have electrical charges; charge is a property of matter. Electricity without mass is like ocean currents without water.

Comment: I wasn't expecting an assessment of a critter but rather an assessment about the flaws of my general understanding.

As such, thank you for the clarification, Cadence!

So, broadly speaking, the minimum requirement for memory retention is some form of (sub)atomic mass? 

I've read up on this site's shapeshifting posts, since it veers in that area, but the baseline of that discussion is still a change in physical body. 

Basically, I'm trying to craft a creature that can create and shape its body without resorting to a higher/different plane of understanding for memory storage.

Comment: This isn't a discussion site, your post should contain all the information to answer your question. We can't say whether your massless being can retain memories without knowing how you're justifying a massless being. Maybe the god of mass has banished your beings from their graces and they are cursed to remain massless, yet retain their memories, growing ever more envious of their Baryonic brethren, still in the mass god's embrace.

Comment: As we don't fully understand how memory is stored in the brain it's hard to say. We don't know optimisations or how to even quantify 'memory'. We can have analogues like computer memory or DNA, but brain memory still eludes us. That's why I VTC until a better question is presented, as we need more information to answer.

Comment: I don't know enough about it to make my own answer based on this, maybe somebody else can, but look into Landauer's limit.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer's_principle

Comment: "Massless" particles have zero rest mass, but they don't have zero mass-energy, and a system of such particles will have mass. It also seems unlikely for any system of such particles to be stable enough to make a living being that persists at all on human timescales without involving normal "baryonic" matter consisting of protons, neutrons, and electrons. "Glueballs" *might* exist, but would be unstable and are difficult to even detect, and would not stay separate from the gluons holding normal matter together.

Comment: @Tar, most things have, mass, even exotic matter. You might be able to (magically, or not) bend space and light to store information in complex structures, but otherwise, as far I know, according to modern physics, a massless being is unlikely, as most particles with complex emergent behavior have mass.

Comment: @Sphennings *no way* all aspects of this question yielding an answer are readily available ! The question is about fundamental properties of living entities, specifically, whether they should have mass to use memory. like living entities normally do: store some information and retrieve it later. Now assuming you adhere a certain physics paradigm, there is a single answer, but it remains theory.. there is no way Tar could include all information needed in advance, to answer this question. Maybe with our help Tar would decide to accept "not plausible", but that does not make this a bad question.

Comment: @Trioxidane why you not knowing the answer to what memory is and how to quantify should be a reason for vtc. Pick some different one, but not this one, lol)

Comment: @MolbOrg it isn't just me. It is everyone. If you can tell me how to quantify a memory (place, action, knowledge, whatever or a combination of any), then I'm all ears. But without that part, the question is unanswerable. That means we need more details or clarity.

Comment: @Trioxidane I suspect(vaguely remember seeing something similar) datascience and neural network theoretical works have answers you are looking for, but you have to google it for yourself. In general, lack of your knowledge, or those you know, or those who you know they know etc - is not a reason to close a question, or else all, _all_ magic related q's should be closed. However it is against purpose of wb - which is to make authors work better using rational, scientific approaches, with experts who can  apply their knowledge in some rational way to someones q. Can't help - skip.

Comment: @MolbOrg neural networks are only the latest way to describe learning. Describing how the brain works has evolved over time. Earlier computers were the best analogy. Neural networks will certainly not be the last. It is like describing DNA with a hard drive. One is so much more complex you can't really compare them. Describing a process we don't understand is just as valid to asking how it would be to live in an alternate dimension. Without further details or clarification it is impossible to answer. If you do have some more information, like with magic questions, you might answer it.

Comment: @Trioxidane theory behind NN is 70 years old, it was proposed in 50's if I remember correctly, and in the essence it just a system of differential equations, theory of which is even older, it got more practial in recent 20 years and sure it blumes in last 10 years. One of the points is, okay you (or let say humanity) does not know _exact_ answer, but we know the answer exists, so this q can wait for 10 years, if you like. But overall, not knowing the answer is not one of the reasons here on wb for vtc's, okay? That is all I wish to say. The rest is interesting, but irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *"massless"* / reality check

**It won't work**

Your [massless entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massless_particle) would consist of a coherent beam of photons, or gluons, which are massless and move at light speed. In fact, internet information reaches us thanks to moving photons, but our optical fiber rods do not *keep* any state. Photons transfer state, or state information from source to target, by means of protocol.

A photon stream carries information, it does not contain an independent state of its own, like its own "memory".

To change state, your massless entity can e.g. loose some of its photons. But it will have no means to read back that information. It could store information, not retrieve it, or change it. One of the comments above already mensioned [Landauer's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle), which implies that setting one bit of (memory) information will require a minimal amount of energy. A massless entity cannot harvest that energy.

Answer (score 0):

Scientifically, mass is the amount of substance and item contains.

As others have stated in the comments beings/creatures must have mass. Photons and gauge bosons are considered [massless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massless_particle).

A rock has mass, but it doesn't have neurons, so it doesn't have memory.

Some time ago I came across the concept that brains are antennae that allow beings to tune in to particular aspects of the "cosmic consciousness". You could incorporate this into your story and adapt it. The creature per se, don't have memory in its own brain, but its brain is accessing memory within the "cosmic consciousness", so no matter what form it takes it is always accessing the same memory bank.

Alternatively, you could adapt the [entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) aspects of quantum theory. This involves two paired particles separated by a distance. Irrespective of the distance between the two particles each particle knows what happens to the other particle, instantaneously.

The particles within your creature's brain are paired with a similar brain, "elsewhere" in the cosmos. It acts as the memory for you creature to access. A bit like a cosmic "[Dropbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox)", where memories are stored.

Comment: *"Each particle knows what happens to the other particle, instantaneously":* No it doesn't. The state of one of the particles becomes determined if the state of the other is known, but the particle itself suffers no change whatsoever. Think of it like this: you have a blue marble and a red marble, and put them at random and without looking in two pouches. One of the pouches is sent to Pluto, the other stays on Earth. If later you look in the pouch on Earth, you will immediately know the color of the marble in the pouch on Pluto, but the marble in the pouch on Pluto was not changed in any way.

Answer (score 0):

## You need some force holding the stuff together.

Memory requires a precise arrangement of substances that can produce a reliable effect. You need some force, probably a new hand wavey physics force, that prevents the particles from flying apart and not interacting.

## You need something holding stuff in one place.

Even if it stays together, you need to make sure it doesn't just get tugged down to the core of the planet by gravity or whatever.

## You need something that can influence the massless substance to do stuff.

You need the substance to be able to form memories and whatever else, so it needs to have some sort of thing able to make it go in particular configurations.

Example.

Chronitons. This is a vaguely timey sounding made up particle. If examined, it's an eight dimensional particle that isn't usually visible by humans, with a complex interaction with other fundamental forces.

This makes the Chromatoms, a hard light based being.

## You need some force holding the stuff together.

Chromitons are capable of bending light, slowing it down, and holding it in place because of Chroniton's quantum interactions with light particles through the Chroniton force.

## You need something holding stuff in one place.

Chronitons have a flexible relationship with gravity that varies based on their configuration. It's believed that the dark energy that causes expansion of the universe is due to massive Chroniton structures between galaxies. Chromatoms can manipulate their framework to move themselves around.

## You need something that can influence the massless substance to do stuff.

The Chromatoms can change their shape into various geometric shapes, with practice forming platonic solids of varying types, and have an innate ability to form memories.

This is because the Chronatins have a wide variety of quantum states that impact how they interact.

Is this scientifically plausible? It's soft science, but it sounds vaguely good. If you want hard science, it's not plausible, but if you're fine with softer science, it's fine.